# Unitary model with cobb-douglas function

Tags: cobb-douglas

We have these following from the first order conditions:

${U_{LA} \over U_C}  = w_A \to MRS_{C,LA}=w_A$

${U_{LB} \over U_C} = w_B \to MRS_{C, LB}=w_B$

${U_{LA} \over U_{LB}} = {w_A \over w_B} \to MRS_{LB, LA} = {wA \over w_B}$

$C + w_A L_A + w_B L_B = (w_A + w_B)T + v_A + v_B$

where $w_A, w_B$ are wage for person $A$ and $B$ respectively

$L_A, L_B$ are leisure for person $A$ and $B$ respectively

$C= C_A+C_B$ (total consumption)

And then it says that from the first three, we can derive the Marshallian demand functions for consumption and leisure:

$C*=C(w_A, w_B, v)$

$L_A* = L_A (w_A,w_B, v)$

$L_B* = L_B (w_A, w_B, v)$

My first question is, what do these mean exactly? What do these actually mean (being a marshallian demand function, how can I do this?), opened up? ($v$ is non-labor income).

Then there comes the marshallian labor supply, which probably is connected to the demand functions, they are given as:

$h_A * = h_A(w_A,w_B,v) = T - L_A (w_A, w_B, v)$

$h_B * = h_B(w_A,w_B,v) = T - L_B (w_A, w_B, v)$

These I can interpret as I get the answer to what are marshallian demand functions, as $T =$ time available to do work (but if someone has the time, maybe you could give a little info?)

Then there comes a Cobb-Douglas function s.t.

$U=C^\alpha L^\beta_A L^\gamma_B$ with $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$

From these results, can be derived following results for the partial derivatives:

${d h_i \over d w_i} > 0$

${d h_i \over d w_j} < 0$

${d j_i \over d v} < 0$

with $i, j = A, B$ and $ i \neq j$ and $v_A + v_B = v$

I dont even know what I need to derivate, but I'm supposed to proof the signs of the last derivatives. Everything is marked as in my source text. This is probably very easy, I'm just confused.

Comment: I'm confused too, about what you're trying to ask here. So it seems that you have problems understanding what Marshallian demand functions are and you've got bogged down by a bunch of messy math. Why don't you take a step back, and ask questions one by one.

Comment: Also, what's all this math for? What is the context? Solving for general equilibrium? What are the utility functions and production function?